# Top Category links disabling click

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, topmenu

Currently my template is using Mega Menu. /RWD/ If  'casting supplies' is clicked on an iPad it will go to the category page and not just drop down the menu.

[image]

How do I change it so that when 'Casting Supplies' is clicked, it does nothing.

I tried:

```
// COMMENT OUT THIS LINE
//$html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';

// ADD THESE LINES
if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
    $html .= '<a onclick="return false" style="text-decoration:none; cursor: default;" href="javascript:;" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'.
    $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';
} else {
    $html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'.
    $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';
}
```

Not sure what else to change. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Which file did you edit?

Comment: app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml

Comment: anyone? have any ideas?

Comment: i'll check tomorrow, no time today sry